# how to fetch google plus user info using swift 4 ,while using social integratioin in my app

Tags: swift4

How to fetch google plus user info using swift 4? Social integration is used to login with google plus but i need most of the user profile info to fetch .

i want to get user profile info like email username dob etc from the google plus login .

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to include your own efforts  (see [help me is not a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

**AppDelegate.swift:**

Initiate google-framework in `AppDelegate.swift`:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Initiate gogle sign-in
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = SocialLogin.Google().clientId
    return true
}
```

handle callback as:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("openUrl scheme: \(url)")
    if let scheme = url.scheme {
        if scheme.hasPrefix("google".lowercased()) {
            return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

**GoogleLogin.swift:**

Add below file `GoogleLogin.swift` in your project:

```
import GoogleSignIn

class GoogleLogin: UIViewController {

    static let shared = GoogleLogin()

    var completionBlock: ((GIDGoogleUser?) -> Void)?

    func login(onCompletion: @escaping ((_ dictionary: [String: String]?) -> Void)) {
        completionBlock = onCompletion

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signOut()
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().signIn()
    }

}

extension GoogleLogin: GIDSignInDelegate {

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        if error == nil {
            self.completionBlock?(user)
        } else {
            print("Error in didSignInFor: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            self.completionBlock?(nil)
        }
    }

    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didDisconnectWith user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {
        print("In didDisconnectWith: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        self.completionBlock?(nil)
    }

}

extension GoogleLogin: GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    func sign(inWillDispatch signIn: GIDSignIn!, error: Error!) {
        //stop your loader here
        //myActivityIndicator.stopAnimating()
    }

    // Present a view that prompts the user to sign in with Google
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, present viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    // Dismiss the "Sign in with Google" view
    func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, dismiss viewController: UIViewController!) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```